# Is there any replacement for WindowsLookAndFeel.java in jdk9

Tags: java, swing, java-9

In JDK 9 with modularization the L&Fs classes are not exported. In my project we are extending this class: 
**com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel**

Curious to know whether Is there any replacement available for this class?

Comment: Note that JEP-260 specify that, as a last resort, there will be a command line flag to use encapsulated internal API. Disclaimre : this comment is purely informational and I would not recommend using it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()`.

Also, never use (or rely on) the undocumented class in the `com.sun` hierarchy of packages, which leads to exactly this type of situation when Oracle decides to move or remove them without warning.

Comment: What is the replacement for com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsButtonUI and om.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsToolBarUI ? Any suggestion

Comment: @vibhas If you don't already see the solution in the answer above, you're going nowhere fast.

Comment: To be fair, it doesn't actually solve all cases where you depend on the UI class. For instance, you might be subclassing it to work around bugs in it. :|    (But at the same time, it was a different question, so it should really be a new question entry.)